# Does make sense to make methods modular or dependent/linked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, parameters

I'm learning python, and really programming in general, and I'm curious of something from a more philosophical perspective. Specifically, I am wondering if it makes sense to make individual methods within a class completely modular, or dependent upon each other in a way.

For example, in my current use case, I am using all the methods in my class in a dependent sort of way, meaning the output or returned value from one method, is then used as a parameter in the next method. Although in this case it would certainly be easier to directly call that method's value in the next method, I am still using generic parameters and coded it in a modular way, and then when I run the script, I list a somewhat long dependency chain in order to call it. I will show an example as I'm not sure what I'm saying will make sense, but I wanted to get your guys opinions on this. Thanks!!

Modular example of 2 of the methods in the class:

```
def get_token(self, values, url):
    self.values = values
    self.url = url
    tls_version = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(self.values).encode("utf-8")
    req = urllib.request.Request(self.url, data)
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(req, context=tls_version).read()
    response_js = json.loads(res)
    return response_js

def parse(self, json_block):
    self.json_block = json_block
    token = self.json_block['access_token']
    inst_url = self.json_block['instance_url']
    return token, inst_url
```

When I call this, it then results in a long list (i.e.):

```
self.parse(get_token(values, url)) ... and this goes on as there are several other methods
```

When it comes to the dependent example...it would essentially look similar, but instead of allowing the specifying of parameters, it would just use the data retrieved from `get_token()` in the function. This would allow for shorter methods and also be much easier to call, but I worry this is the wrong way to go about it as it doesn't allow for versatility.

Any opinions on the matter is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion (as that's what this is), the most useful way to do it is by having them all detached from each other, but have a function which calculates them all together.

See the code:

```
class Foo:
    def method1(self, var1, var2):
        # do things
        return var3, var4

    def method2(self, var1, var2):
        # do things
        return var3

    def method3(self, var1):
        # do things
        return var3, var4, var5

    def method4(self, var1, var2, var3):
        # do things
        return var3

    def calculate_meaning_of_life(self, var1, var2):
        inter_var1, inter_var2 = method1(var1, var2)

        inter_var3 = method2(inter_var1, inter_var2)

        inter_var4, inter_var5, inter_var6 = method3(inter_var3)

        answer = method4(inter_var4, inter_var5, inter_var6)

        return answer # happens to always output 42
```

Here, you can call `Foo.method3` with any parameters you like, and get it's results straight away, without having to go through other functions or anything painful like that. Also, you can quickly calculate them all together by calling the `Foo.calculate_meaning_of_life` func (NOTE: not on one line, as that would be very unreadable) with whatever variables you want, and it does all the heavy lifting for you.

Especially from a debug perspective, you want to be able to call all of them separately and analyse what they return, because, in the end, if they can only be run together, why not just have one function?

Also, if you ever get to making packages for others to install, they will find reasons to just use `Foo.method2` for their specific project, so you should make all of the code you have written as easy to access as possible.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it is for readability, because utimately you (and most likely others as well) are going to have to review your code.  You want a method that works for you in this regard.

This is my method:

Keep every method distinct from the others.  If you are considering using helper methods, it would be a good idea to keep them in the method they are used by, or (if there are a lot used in the same operation) just group them in their own class.

```
class MyClass:
    def distinct_method(self):
        def distinct_helper():
            # helper
            return ", right?"
        # do some distinct stuff
        return other_distinct_method() + distinct_helper()

    def other_distinct_method(self.):
        # do some other distinct stuff
        return "it should be distinct"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print MyClass().distinct_method()
```

A good rule of thumb is to not make a helper method a part of a class unless it is used by more than one other instance method, e.g.:

```
class MyClass2:
    def helper(self):
        return "help!"

    def method1(self):
       return "I use " + self.helper()

    def method2(self):
        return "I also use " + self.helper()
```

instead of

```
class MyClass1:
    def helper(self):
        return "help!"

    def method1(self):
       return "I use " + self.helper()

    def method2(self):
        return "I don't use helper!"
```